# Force refresh/build list of redirected printers in RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, printing

Hope someone can offer some advice.

We have Windows Server 2019, where users access a remote app or desktop via RDP. They can print to their local printers through printer redirection.

I understand UmRdpService (Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector) is responsible for building the redirected printers (and drives) list, but I've noticed the printers list doesn't refresh until possibly a minute after signing in or reconnecting.

That delay is a bit of a problem for us, and one solution would be to force the build of the redirected printers list sooner on signing in, and perhaps on (re)connection.

Is there any way to prioritize or otherwise automatically force a redirected printers refresh for that user, on sign in or connect.
If not, can we configure how often UmRdpService makes a check for new printers?

Comment: There might be a problem with the printer driver that is set up on the Remote Desktop server.

Comment: Check if old rdp printer ports are not getting cleared out for some reason with powershell: `Get-PrinterPort | Format-Table -auto` and clear them out if there are any for disconnected sessions (they are supposed to get deleted when terminal server restarts). I've seen it take 10 min or more to get printers all set up. Make sure the server is up to date too - one of the recent 2019 updates fixed an issue with this kind of thing

Comment: Thanks for the advice on this. I've been checking the printer port list (have been using print manager) and it looks to be cleaning up correctly. I am becoming suspicious that the delay in building the redirected printer list may be linked to the local environment, ie. local firewall and/or bandwidth. Will work on that theory tomorrow